# OData in Web API 2 with embeddable links for resources

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, embedded-resource

There is support for embedded resources in OData in ASP.NET Web API 2. Is there a project or sample that demonstrates this?

Comment: Do you mean Media entities and named streams?

Comment: @RaghuRamNadiminti Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can either use named streams or Media Link Entry (MLE). Read about it [here](http://www.odata.org/2010/10/enhancing-odata-support-for-streams/).

Named streams seem to suit your scenario better. There is a sample [here](https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/6237208) that shows how to use extensibility points in web API OData to do named streams.